# Git: briefly go back by a few commits and then come back

Tags: git

I am on branch `myBranch` and I have some unstaged, uncommitted changes in my working dir.

I want to briefly go back by a few commits on this branch to just peek at the code, so I do this:

`git checkout <specific-commit-hash>`

After I recompiled the checkouted code etc., I want to "undo everything", that is: retrieve my previously unstaged and uncommitted changes.

Perhaps `git stash` could find usage here?

Comment: yes, git stash is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, `git stash` would be a good choice here. You would `git stash` on the branch you are currently in, then `git checkout` the branch you wish to work on. When you're finished, `git stash pop` to restore your stashed code.

Some good resources on `git stash`:

- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning

Answer (score -2):

Briefly, `git stash`.

```
git stash
git checkout <something>
// do stuff
git reset .  // maybe you want to discard edits
git checkout <back to the start>
git stash pop
```

Comment: @DaemonPainter Can we use `commit-id` in place of `<something>` or we need to use `branch-name`??

Comment: mmm, care on explaining why the -1?
@AnkitJindal, I feel that explaining git checkout here is probably out-of-scope. Yes, You may use any valid indicator, such as a SHA, or a branch name. Depends on what you want to checkout.

Comment: I have not given you -1